# Why can't I create a new list Cusom setting?

Tags: customsetting

[image]

I'm working on a Partial copy sandbox with a standard System Administrator profile User.
Why can I only create Hierarchy Custom settings? In production I can create list Type custom Settings with the same User.

I couldn't find any related info in either the Custom Settings limits :
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_limits.htm&type=5

or Defining custom settings help :

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_define.htm&type=5

Comment: I ran into this the other day & ended up giving up and moving on, but it struck me as really weird. I couldn't find anything about limits or depreciated features either. Worth checking to see if you can create a list custom settings through the metadata api or other, non-UI methods of metadata creation.